# What does "squat" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Following is a quote from the novel, "The Girl on the Train" by Paula Hawkins (emphasis mine):

> "My laptop is on the floor next to my bed; it sits there, a **squat**, accusatory presence."

What does "squat" refer to in this context?

Dictionary provides the following two meanings:

1. "crouch or sit with one's knees bent and one's heels close to or touching one's buttocks or the back of one's thighs"

Wonder how will a laptop squat?!

2. "unlawfully occupy an uninhabited building or settle on a piece of land"

The girl in question owns the laptop, which is lying next to her bed, which is in a home she rents. So definitely the laptop isn't occupying that place illegally.

So what exactly does it mean?

Comment: The word **squat** is an adjective here.

Comment: @CowperKettle okay that makes sense now. You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word [squat](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/squat) as an adjective means:

*short* and *thick* or *low* and *wide*, especially in a way which is not attractive.

> a squat little old man.
>
> The brown buildings were old and squat
>
> The cook was short and squat, with thick eyebrows and a slight
>   moustache.
>
> he was muscular and squat.
>
> a row of ugly, squat houses

And the lines just before (the quote you have mentioned) show why the laptop has
a "accusatory presence":

> I never learn. I wake with a crushing sensation of wrongness, **of
>   shame**, and I know immediately that I’ve done something stupid. I go
>   through my awful, achingly familiar ritual of trying to remember
>   exactly what I did. I sent an email. That’s what it was. At some point last night, **Tom got promoted back up the list of men I think about, and I sent him an email**. My laptop is on the floor next to my bed; it sits there, a squat, accusatory presence. .

http://studynovels.com/Page/Story?bookId=120&pageNo=26